# How to transform xml with self iterating nested complex elements into flat structure

Tags: xslt

I need to transform an XML file with multiple complex elements into flat structure. This is a sample structure of my large xml file which need to be formatted into flat structure as in required output.

Input Xml -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:Response xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/response" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/response response.xsd ">
    <tns:Consumer>
        <tns:ConsumerID>tns:ConsumerID</tns:ConsumerID>
        <tns:Relation>
            <tns:ParentEntity>
                <tns:PEID>PE1</tns:PEID>
                <tns:Customer>
                    <tns:CustID>1</tns:CustID>
                    <tns:Relation>
                        <tns:ParentEntity>
                            <tns:PEID>PE2</tns:PEID>
                            <tns:Customer/>
                            <tns:Account/>
                        </tns:ParentEntity>
                        <tns:ChildEntity>
                            <tns:CEID>CE1</tns:CEID>
                            <tns:Customer/>
                            <tns:Account/>
                        </tns:ChildEntity>
                    </tns:Relation>
                </tns:Customer>
                <tns:Account>
                    <tns:AccountId>1</tns:AccountId>
                    <tns:Relation>
                        <tns:ParentEntity>
                            <tns:PEID>PE3</tns:PEID>
                            <tns:Customer/>
                            <tns:Account/>
                        </tns:ParentEntity>
                        <tns:ChildEntity>
                            <tns:CEID>CE2</tns:CEID>
                            <tns:Customer/>
                            <tns:Account/>
                        </tns:ChildEntity>
                    </tns:Relation>
                </tns:Account>
            </tns:ParentEntity>
            <tns:ChildEntity>
                <tns:CEID>CE3</tns:CEID>
                <tns:Customer>
                    <tns:CustID>1</tns:CustID>
                    <tns:Relation>
                        <tns:ParentEntity>
                            <tns:PEID>PE4</tns:PEID>
                            <tns:Customer/>
                            <tns:Account/>
                        </tns:ParentEntity>
                        <tns:ChildEntity>
                            <tns:CEID>CE4</tns:CEID>
                            <tns:Customer/>
                            <tns:Account/>
                        </tns:ChildEntity>
                    </tns:Relation>
                </tns:Customer>
                <tns:Account>
                    <tns:AccountId>1</tns:AccountId>
                    <tns:Relation>
                        <tns:ParentEntity>
                            <tns:PEID>PE5</tns:PEID>
                            <tns:Customer/>
                            <tns:Account/>
                        </tns:ParentEntity>
                        <tns:ChildEntity>
                            <tns:CEID>CE5</tns:CEID>
                            <tns:Customer/>
                            <tns:Account/>
                        </tns:ChildEntity>
                    </tns:Relation>
                </tns:Account>
            </tns:ChildEntity>
        </tns:Relation>
    </tns:Consumer>
</tns:Response>
```

Required Output XML -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:Response xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/Required" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/Required Required.xsd ">
    <tns:Consumer>
        <tns:Customer>
            <tns:CustID>tns:CustID</tns:CustID>
        </tns:Customer>
        <tns:Account>
            <tns:AccountId>tns:AccountId</tns:AccountId>
        </tns:Account>
        <tns:Customer>
            <tns:CustID>tns:CustID</tns:CustID>
        </tns:Customer>
        <tns:Account>
            <tns:AccountId>tns:AccountId</tns:AccountId>
        </tns:Account>
        <tns:Customer/>
        <tns:Account/>
        <tns:Customer/>
        <tns:Account/>
    </tns:Consumer>
</tns:Response>
```

The output xml need to have only customer and Account complex elements in a flat structure. How to achieve this using XSLT.  Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was not sure what do You mean by "flat map" as Your `Customer`-`Account` structure defines relations to parent and children. Here is an XSLT snippet to just flat all `Customer` and `Account` mentioned in an XML. It can be tweaked to use only children on each level. But I couldn't figure out it exactly by analysing Your expected result as there are no matching Ids corresponding to ids in XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/response" >

<xsl:template match="/">
  <tns:Response>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </tns:Response>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tns:Consumer">
  <tns:Consumer>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </tns:Consumer>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tns:Customer">
  <tns:Customer>
    <tns:CustID><xsl:value-of select="tns:CustID"/></tns:CustID>
  </tns:Customer>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tns:Account">
  <tns:Account>
    <tns:AccountId><xsl:value-of select="tns:AccountId"/></tns:AccountId>
  </tns:Account>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```